# Socket.io, Mongodb returning undefined to frontend

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

I want to use socekt.io for a new project I am building. I am using socket.io for a login component and will be using socket.io in the future to update pages like a chat app. I am also using mongoose to handle my mongodb connection. I am taking in a username, and returning a password to my front end to be bcryptjs `compareSync` hashed. The problem I am having is that whatever is returned to the front end is undefined. When I print out what is returned to the front end, it prints out the value I am looking for though. Something is going on between the backend emitting something, and the frontend receiving something but I don't know what is it exactly. Here is my code for the back end:

```
const express = require('express')
const socket = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');
const router = require('./router');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Player = require('../models/player.model');



require('dotenv').config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true });

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open',() => {
    console.log('MongoDB database connection established successfully')
});

const io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('We have a new connection');

    socket.on('login', ({ username }, callback) => {
        console.log(username);

        Player.find({"username": username}, function (err, player) {
            if(err) {
                console.log("there has been an error"), {player: null}
            }
            socket.emit('id', { password: player[0]['password'].toString(), id : player[0]['_id']})
        })   })})

app.use(router);

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Server is working'))
```

Here is my code for the front end:

```
    const ENDPOINT = 'localhost:5000';
    async function submitAccount (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        socket.emit('login', { username });

        socket.on("id", (response) => {
            setPassword2(String(response['password']));
            id = response['id']; console.log(id);
            console.log(password2)
        }); 
        try {
            if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, password2) == true) {

                props.setCookie("id", id);
                setAccess(true);
                access2 = true;
                console.log(access2)
                console.log('works')

            }
            else {

                setErrorType('Invalid Password')
                setErrorMsg('There is an issue with your password. Please try again')
                setOpenModal(true)
                console.log(password);
                console.log(password2);
            }
        }
        catch {
            setErrorType('Invalid Username')
            setErrorMsg('This username does not exist. Please try another')
            setOpenModal(true)
        }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

When you do the socket.on, it should include the whole statement you are looking to change with the socket.io output. See below:

async function submitAccount (e) {

```
    e.preventDefault();

    socket.emit('login', { username });

    socket.on("id", (response) => {
        setPassword2(String(response['password']));
        id = response['id']; console.log(id);
        console.log(password2)

    if (password2 != undefined) {
    try {
        if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, password2) == true) {

            props.setCookie("id", id);
            setAccess(true);
            access2 = true;
            console.log(access2)
            console.log('works')

        }
```

}